Dense Time Series Data
Picture of my plot
Picture of my code
I am trying to graph some dense time series data, but I keep getting a box. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to see the overall trend of this dataset so I can get an idea of how it is distributed?
I tried disable it in the rc parameters.

Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
